# How to track issue of AOT build error (Angular 5.2.9)

Tags: angular, build, production, aot

I want production build with AOT for my project.
 My AOT production build is successful by command

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot=true --build-optimizer=false  --sourcemaps=true
```

But after running http-server, I get following error in console.

```
 Uncaught Error: StaticInjectorError[t -> function(){}]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> function(){}]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for function(){}!
    at t.get (core.js:1002)
    at core.js:1300
    at _t (core.js:1242)
    at t.get (core.js:1110)
    at core.js:1300
    at _t (core.js:1242)
    at t.get (core.js:1110)
    at Ni (core.js:10854)
    at core.js:10916
    at Vi (core.js:10868)
```

Can anyone please help or guide me so that I can track the error?

Comment: try to debug in serve mod .. you've a DI problem

Comment: Looks like it's connected with JitCompiler

Comment: Without aot i.e. '--aot=false' this error is not coming

Comment: Yes @federicoscamuzzi this error seems due to DI but I am unable to track for particular which module or service this error is getting thrown

Comment: Are you using `compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync`?

Comment: @yurzui yes for dynamic components